# Change class packages for context in Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a problem with context configuration. I have my test class in package 
`com.my.class.TestClass` in test module (src/test/java). I'm using there `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to include `applicationContextForTests.xml`.
In this file, I have a `component-scan:

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.class.configuration"/>`

But,

this `com.my.class.configuration` is in `src/main/java` and also in `src/test/java`, where I have `ConfigurationTestClass.class`

In base-package I want to use `com.my.class.configuration` from `src/main/java`, not from `src/test/java`. The problem is, when I use `com.my.class.configuration`
in `base-package` it points to package from `src/test/java`, not from `src/main/java`

Is it possible to configure this xml file to use `base-package` from src/main/java?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. It is necessary to add new xml location into `@ContextConfiguration`. For example:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/context1.xml",
        "context2.xml"}
```

where context1.xml is in src/main/java module and context2.xml is in src/test/java module. In first one I include all packages from src/main/java.